# How to scrape multiple image's links in same position blank that position if there's no picture

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an exam website that has 2 classes that I need (Topic class and Choice class). So, in a choice class (actually, it's a choice to answer) some questions ares image choice (4 choices is image), so, I want to scrape 4 image's links in the same position in array (1 position in array is 1 question).

And another question for me, how can I blank the array position if there is no picture?

Actually, I will random question's number to get data in 4 array (Topic,Choice,topic's image, choice's image) then I will get the data from these array to display in next applications.

Here is an example question and the HTML code:

```
<div class="cssQue"><div class="cssExTopic">ข้อที่ 38 :  <ul><li>ภาพใดแสดง เกลียวน๊อตตามแบบมาตรฐาน</li></ul></div><div class="cssExChoice"><ul><li><input type="checkbox" name="a"> 1  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A1.jpg"></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="a"> 2  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A2.jpg"></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="a"> 3  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A3.jpg"></li><li><input type="checkbox" name="a"> 4  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A4.jpg"></li><li><br></li><li> คำตอบที่ถูกต้อง :<font color="white"> 3</font></li></ul></div></div>
```

The image's URL that I need should be like:

```
https://my-project-1471674425170.firebaseapp.com/drawing/drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A1.jpg
```

Comment: show your code. you could also add url for this page or some HTML of this page to see it.

Comment: the content is not in English. I'm not sure if I post it, may not fit.

Comment: put url in question - maybe someone can read it and can help. HTML uses the same tags so it can be useful.

Comment: I can only post the example image. (I can not post the url because the copyright issue)

Comment: at least copy HTML as text in question. Image with code and HTML is useless. People can't copy text from image to test it and create solutions.

Comment: Okay. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your examples are similar, then the following approach could work. This will also catch the text associated with each `<li>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="cssQue">
   <div class="cssExTopic">
      ข้อที่ 38 :  
      <ul>
         <li>ภาพใดแสดง เกลียวน๊อตตามแบบมาตรฐาน</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="cssExChoice">
      <ul>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="a"> 1  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A1.jpg"></li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="a"> 2  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A2.jpg"></li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="a"> 3  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A3.jpg"></li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="a"> 4  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A4.jpg"></li>
         <li><br></li>
         <li> คำตอบที่ถูกต้อง :<font color="white"> 3</font></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>"""

base_url = "https://my-project-1471674425170.firebaseapp.com/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
div = soup.find('div', class_="cssExChoice")
urls = []

for li in div.find_all('li'):
    img = li.find('img', src=True)

    # Was there an image present?
    if img:
        urls.append((li.get_text(strip=True), base_url + li.img['src'].lstrip('/.')))
    else:
        urls.append((li.get_text(strip=True), None))

# Display the results
for text, url in urls:
    print(f'"{text}" - {url}')
```

Giving you the text and URL pairs as follows:

```
"1  :" - https://my-project-1471674425170.firebaseapp.com/drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A1.jpg
"2  :" - https://my-project-1471674425170.firebaseapp.com/drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A2.jpg
"3  :" - https://my-project-1471674425170.firebaseapp.com/drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A3.jpg
"4  :" - https://my-project-1471674425170.firebaseapp.com/drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A4.jpg
"" - None
"คำตอบที่ถูกต้อง :3" - None
```

In your example there are 6 `<li>` items, but only 4 have images. The list returned has the last two entries as `None`.

The topic could also be extracted as follows:

```
div_topic = soup.find('div', class_="cssExTopic")
topic = ' - '.join(text.strip() for text in div_topic.strings if text.strip())
print(topic)
```

Giving:

```
อที่ 38 : - ภาพใดแสดง เกลียวน๊อตตามแบบมาตรฐาน
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Mr.Martin, Can I ask you another one ?

Comment: If I want to scrap all in class, I mean I need text and image link same like the main question. Can I do that ?

Comment: Which text do you mean?  The `<li>` text is just `1   :`. I have updated the script to show how this could be done.

Comment: Yea, It's about   `[1  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A1.jpg, 2  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A2.jpg, 3  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A3.jpg, 4  : <img src="./drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A4.jpg]`

Comment: Sorry for late reply @MartinEvans  I just notice your error, the result in the URL image. It show only the same pic as ` drawing_files/S190T1P249_20060124_224403_A1.jpg` . It should give a 4 image's URL.

Comment: Sorry, it should have said `li.img` not `soup.img`